# Cases of types vs fields of records in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The two following pieces of code seem really similar. However there *must* be some differences and I am hoping that someone could point them out.

```
data Animal = Cat | Dog
speak :: Animal -> String
speak Cat = "meowh"
speak Dog = "wouf"
```

and

```
data Animal = Animal { speak :: String }
cat = Animal { speak = "meowh"}
dog = Animal { speak = "wouf" }
```

Answer (score 26):

Good question! You've struck at the heart of one of the fundamental problems of software engineering. Per Wadler, it's called [*the Expression Problem*](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/expression/expression.txt), and, roughly summarised, the question is:

> Should it be easy to add new operations, or new types of data?

Your first example makes it **easy to add new operations** to existing animals. We can process `Animal` values in all sorts of ways without changing the definition of `Animal`:

```
numberOfTeeth :: Animal -> Int
numberOfTeeth Cat = 30
numberOfTeeth Dog = 42

food :: Animal -> String
food Cat = "Fish"
food Dog = "Sausages"  -- probably stolen from a cartoon butcher
```

The downside is that it's **hard to add new types** of animal. You have to add new constructors to `Animal` and change all the existing operations:

```
data Animal = Cat | Dog | Crocodile

speak :: Animal -> String
speak Cat = "miaow"
speak Dog = "woof"
speak Crocodile = "RAWR"

numberOfTeeth :: Animal -> Int
numberOfTeeth Cat = 30
numberOfTeeth Dog = 42
numberOfTeeth Crocodile = 100000  -- I'm not a vet

food :: Animal -> String
food Cat = "Fish"
food Dog = "Sausages"
food Crocodile = "Human flesh"
```

Your second example flips the matrix, making it **easy to add new types**,

```
crocodile = Animal { speak = "RAWR" }
```

but **hard to add new functions** - it means adding new fields to `Animal` and updating all the existing animals.

```
data Animal = Animal {
    speak :: String,
    numberOfTeeth :: Int,
    food :: String
}
cat = Animal {
    speak = "miaow",
    numberOfTeeth = 30,
    food = "Fish"
}
dog = Animal {
    speak = "woof",
    numberOfTeeth = 42,
    food = "Sausages"
}
crocodile = Animal {
    speak = "RAWR",
    numberOfTeeth = 100000,
    food = "Human flesh"
}
```

Don't underestimate how big of a deal the Expression Problem is! If you're working on a published library, you may find yourself contending with operations or types defined by someone you've never met in a codebase you can't change. You have to think carefully about the way you expect people to use your system, and decide how to orient the design of your library.

Over the years, smart people have invented lots of clever ways of solving the Expression Problem, to support new operations *and* new types. These solutions tend to be complicated, using the most advanced features of the most modern programming languages. In the real world, this is just another trade-off engineers have to consider - is solving the Expression Problem worth the code-complexity it'll cause?

Comment: I'm facing a related situation right now designing a merge API for `Data.Map`. The "open" approach is preferable in some ways. For one thing, I can implement it without GADTs and therefore maintain compatibility with Report Haskell. For another, I don't need huge case analyses everywhere. But it's unpleasant in some other ways; in particular, it's much harder for me to take advantage of what I know about the behavior of values constructed in particular manners to optimize things.

Comment: @Benjamin: "Over the years, very smart people have invented lots of clever ways of solving the Expression Problem, to support new operations and new types" What are these solutions ?

Comment: @baxbaxwalanuksiwe There's too much literature, and too many different approaches, for me to cite exhaustively here. Kiselyov touches on it in his [tagless final notes](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf); there's a [Scala paper](http://scala-lang.org/docu/files/IC_TECH_REPORT_200433.pdf) by Zenger and Odersky; Torgersen has done [work](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~madst/ecoop04/main.pdf) on it in Java and C#. That's just a starter - I advise following the references from those papers and doing some of your own Googling to learn about the full variety of solutions

Comment: That is a difference from the point of view of code mutability (ie. the developer). Is there some difference at the computer level (performance or security, for instance)?

Comment: @ernesto There _may_ be a (very minor) performance difference between the two but you'd be firmly in the realm of microoptimisations. The impact on flexibility is much more important.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's assign the types the names, which closer reflect their essence:

```
data AnimalType =
  Cat | Dog

newtype Phrase =
  Phrase { phrase :: String }
```

It already becomes evident that they are very different and clearly isolatable.

A phrase here is a way more general thing. It can be spoken not just by animals, but by robots at least as well. But more so it can not only be spoken, but also be transformed with operations like upper-casing and etc. Such operations would make no sense for the `AnimalType` type.

`AnimalType` OTOH has its own benefits. By matching the type, you can pick a type of food the animal needs or its size and etc. You can't do that on `Phrase`.

You can also have both types coexist in isolation in your application and have a transformation (and, hence, a dependency) from the more specific to the more general one:

```
module Animal where

import qualified Phrase

speakPhrase :: Animal -> Phrase.Phrase
speakPhrase =
  Phrase.Phrase . speak
```

What's causing your confusion is that your problem lacks the context of an application. Once you'll provide it to yourself, you'll get the info on what you actually need this thing to do and which data it'll operate on.